# Styles defined in BODY (necessity) are not applied in IE 7,8,9

Tags: css, internet-explorer

**SOLVED** Internet Explorer has a time sheet limit of linked style sheets, so that's why my stylesheets were ignored. More about this issue on: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262161

---

I spent half a day trying to find the issue: The styles defined in BODY element are not applied in IE 7,8,9. The copy of the page is visible on http://joskaweb.cz/hub.html.

My styles are on line 233 (it's minified CSS from LESS).

I was not able to find the reason why, but when I remove styles from lines 112 to 119 it starts working, so there has to be something in there, but I'm not able to find it.

Unfortunately, due to brand restrictions I have no access to Wordperss template we are using (I can only edit page content), so I have to put the styles into BODY element. The page linked above is a copy I created for test purpouses. I need to find the bug to smash it in support team face, otherwise I won't get help from them.

Comment: Explorer hates invalid HTML, and yet that's what you're feeding it.  And from the rest of your description, you really have a people problem which has no programming solution.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjoskaweb.cz%2Fhub.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: I've never seen such a bloated template (34 external CSS files!) and I don't see any _"styles defined in BODY element"_.  Please edit your question to include the actual relevant code.  Besides, this question should be written to remain useful to others forever... not just until you fix your site.

Comment: CSS styles on lines 231-233 are inside your `<head></head>`, not `<body>`?  And you can't seriously expect us to dig though 34 external style sheets looking for an unspecified problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using html5 elements, like header. And this elements does not work in IE 7&8.
Use this JavaScript code to fix it.

```
document.createElement('header');
```

And you must give header in CSS `display: block`

**Or use**

[html5shim](https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/)

This source code adds new HTML5 elements, too. But it also supports printing HTML5 elements and includes the default styles for HTML5 elements, like block on article and section.

Comment: How is `createElement('header')` any different than simply using `<header></header>` on the page like the OP is already doing?

Comment: @Sparky672 [this article](http://paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/) gives the background on the technique.